# How to resize subviews inside XIB/NIB at runtime

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image inside my XIB, and I want to resize it depending on the actual screen's size. How do I do this?

In a regular view controller, I was able to do the following:

```
myImage.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width * 0.40 // it will always be 40% of my view's size
```

I tried something similar with XIB class, but it does not resize my image at all.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // properties
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Setup
    setup() // trying to resize the image here
}
```

Comment: Where in the view's lifecycle are you currently trying to size it?

Comment: Update question, please check. Thanks!

Comment: What is a `XIB class`? Do you mean a `UIViewController` subclass? If so you probably want to adjust the image size relative to the superview's size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: My XIB class is a subclass of UIView, not UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `UIView` subclass? Put the resizing code inside `layoutSubviews`. You'll probably also need to call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` (in that order) inside your view controller immediately after loading the xib.